# htaccess rewrite https removing secure prefix

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to use the htaccess to rewrite from

https://secure25.securewebsession.com/domain.co.uk/wordpress

to http://www.domain.co.uk/wordpress

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, try this (make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secure25\.securewebsession\.com$
RewriteRule ^(www\.)?domain\.co\.uk(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.uk$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Comment: Wow that was quick. Silly question – where do I place domain.co.uk?

Comment: I didn't understand you question ? :| (but I have a question, do you have only one domain that you want to redirect to ? because I wrote a rule that will work with any domain)

Comment: Sorry – I tried the rewrite and it redirected back to wordpress.com for some reason so to clarify where in the rewrite do I put mydomain.co.uk to that it redirects to the correct address. I've only got one site that needs the rule.